# Is there a way to apply all flyway schema versions to a new database to bring it up to date?

Tags: database-migration, flyway

I use flyway for DB schema migrations.

But now I also want to make it possible to dynamically create a new database (for testing), update it to the latest schema, and fill it with test data.

Is it possible to have flyway baseline a new DB and apply ALL schema version scripts sequentially so the DB is updated to the latest state?

I could not find any examples of this. I don't want to have a separate process or scripts for creating a new DB with the right schema.

Comment: If you apply Flyway to a new database, because none of the migrations will have been applied and recorded, it will apply them all. Assuming your schema is encoded in those migrations (you didn't e.g. start part-way through from a database with some initial schema), the new DB will then have the right schema.

Comment: What if it's been a few years and I build up a lot of schema versions? Whats the process for cleaning them up? Could I re-baseline with a new version 1 schema somehow? Is that sort of process documented anywhere?

Comment: That's up to you - you _could_ do that, but then you'd have to have conditions in the new migrations to handle the two cases 1. new DB; and 2. already-up-to-date DB (see e.g. https://flywaydb.org/blog/skipexecutingmigrations). Given the effort involved, vs. how quickly the migrations can actually be applied even if a few aren't entirely needed or are subsequently reversed, it's probably not worth it.

Comment: Thats what I wanted to avoid. I could just leave all my versions and if they don't build up that much it won't be an issue, but after a while I could see it getting unwieldily. Is it possible to do something like re-baseline and create a new V1, but skip that version for my production DB? The new V1 then would have the current schema that newly created test DBs use to come up to date. Then adding V2, V3, etc work as usual until I want to reset to V1 again. Is something like that possible?